# How do I make Apache user tracking cookie decimal instead of hex?

Tags: mysql, apache, cookies, hex, decimal

It used to be that the cookie value was decimal.  But something has changed and it is now hex.

Needs to go into mysql db bigint field.

It's being captured as env var and put into log/db with log format %{var}e.  So converting the var to decimal work too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture the hex string 'ABC', then convert it to decimal:

```
CONV('ABC', 16, 10)  -->  2748
```

Or store it into a `BINARY` column using

```
UNHEX('...')
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  Is there a way to do the conversion in the Apache environment space?  The value is also included in the log file.  So it would be a bonus to have it in decimal there too (same in both the db and log file).  Again.  Thanks.